# joining multiple tables in a single select statement

Tags: select, union

```
SELECT user_id as user_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name
FROM users u
WHERE (first_name like '%r%' or last_name like '%r%') 

UNION

SELECT provider_id as provider_id, provider_name as name
FROM providers
WHERE ( provider_name like '%r%')
```

Using the above query i get

```
user_id name
5        Richard
6        Rowen
12       Riley
21       Rowen providers
```

Rowen providers has a provider_id which is 21. but the column name is user_id. How can i get a different column name for provider_id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the column in two and supply fake values where you can't get an actual value:

```
SELECT '' as provider_id, user_id as user_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name
FROM users u
WHERE (first_name like '%r%' or last_name like '%r%') 

UNION

SELECT provider_id as provider_id, '' as user_id, provider_name as name
FROM providers
WHERE ( provider_name like '%r%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a union, the second query is inheriting column names from the first query. This is causing your data to be inaccurate after execution. If I were you, I'd do a JOIN instead of a UNION. This will preserve column names of the second query, and will present the data in a manner that is easily readable. For rows that are providers, the user information will be NULL, and for rows that are users, the provider information will be NULL. The best suggestion I can give you is to try not to combine two different types of data in one column whenever possible. User_Id and Provider_Id should not be in the same column since they have different meanings.

Try:

```
SELECT u.user_id, CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as user_name,
       p.provider_id, p.provider_name
FROM users u, providers p
WHERE (u.first_name like '%r%' or u.last_name like '%r%') or
      (p.provider_name like '%r%')
```